# SecurityException on Android Q for acessing ExternalStorage with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Tags: android, uri, android-10.0, securityexception, documents-provider

I'm trying to fetch all images from a specific folder for displaying in a recycler view, but no matter what, i get a SecurityException.

I'm currently doing it the following way:

Code for selecting folder

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    lastRequest = REQUEST_IMAGENS;
    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_IMAGENS);
```

onActivityResult

```
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(data.getData(),data.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

and for fetching each individual bitmap (this part specifically i tried many different variations, but all with same result)

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(xContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(stringUri + "%3A" + (archiveName + ".png"))));
```

I think the problem is on the last bit of code, but i really dont know what else to try.

The exception i get is:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload%2FSaurus%20-%20Cadastro%20-%20Imagens%3A2171.png from pid=13239, uid=10425 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

I've retrieved the persisted permissions with getPersistedUriPermissions and it contains the following uri:

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload%2FSaurus%20-%20Cadastro%20-%20Imagens
```

I'm almost certan i cant manually append the file name like i did, but i dont know what i have to do instead.

I've read other posts and there are lots of different answers, but none worked and i tried almost everything i could find.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Edited:

The problem is i only want the user to select the folder, not all the images, and then i will search the images i want within the folder, in a loop that i omitted because its not part of the problem. All i want to know is how to open a specific file within a folder i have permissions.

Comment: `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);` You better remove all flags as they are useless. You cannot grant anything.

Comment: `.openInputStream(Uri.parse(stringUri + "%3A" + (archiveName + ".png"))));` No. You are trying to build an uri for a file. But this is not the way to obtain such an uri.

Comment: `trying to fetch all images from a specific folder` Where? I dont see you doing that. Where are you listing its contents?

Comment: @blackapps I did not post the full code, and i also didnt explain it correctly.
I'm not trying to fetch all images, but i search within the folder for some specific images (which should be all, but thats not important)
I left out a for loop, as it was not important

Comment: Yes, i am trying to build an uri for a file, so i can turn it into a bitmap. Sorry, but your comments are far from useful, i know i am doing some things wrong, thats why i posted the question

Comment: List the content of the folder to begin with. Then you have all uries.

Comment: @blackapps How about explaining how to do it instead of telling us what doesn't work? We, who find this page on Google are not interested in what doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Code for selecting folder

As blackapps noted, get rid of those flags, as they are useless in this context.

> I think the problem is on the last bit of code

Correct. You cannot create valid document `Uri` values manually.

> but i really dont know what else to try

What you want is not reliable. You are making assumptions about display names of documents in a tree that may not match reality. But, if you are willing to live with compatibility problems, you can do this:

Step #1: Call `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()`, passing in the tree `Uri` that you got from `onActivityResult()` to give you a `DocumentFile` for the tree

Step #2: Call `listFiles()` on that `DocumentFile` to give you an array of `DocumentFile` objects representing the contents of that tree root

Step #3: Use `getName()` and `isFile()` to filter that array to the subset that match your desired naming scheme

Step #4: For those that match, call `getUri()` to get the `Uri` for those documents, which you can pass to your favorite image-loading library

Comment: I know that some files might not be there, but thats expected. For those, i'll use a placeholder image.
I'm going to try it now, thanks.

Comment: It ended up being very slow, so i had to rewrite my logic, but it worked. Thank you very much

Comment: Is there seriously no faster way? How do file explorer programs show files WAY faster than this method?

Comment: @JohnGlen: Seasoned developers can work directly with [`DocumentsContract`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract) and its nested classes. This API is somewhat cumbersome and poorly documented, which is why I generally steer people towards `DocumentFile` (unoptimized but an easier API). Also, bear in mind that manufacturer-installed file managers might simply be using filesystem APIs, as manufacturer-installed apps can have greater access rights than ordinary apps, if the manufacturer wants.

Comment: "get rid of those flags, as they are useless in this contex" then how do we should use these flags?

Comment: @Simon: If you have permissions that you want to grant to others, use `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and/or `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION`. You will see this a lot with `ACTION_VIEW`, for example. If you are writing a `DocumentsProvider`, you may have a need for those other two.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks but I was talking about flags like Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION

Comment: @Simon: That too would only be relevant if you have permissions that are you are trying to grant to others. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent?hl=en#FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION).